# Is it compulsory to install add-on in order to deploy Mongo in Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, heroku

Is it compulsory to install add-on in order to deploy Mongo in Heroku like MLAB MongoDB, Compose MongoDB, Object Rocket for MongoDB in order to make the apps run? Because right now I'm having issue deploying my nodejs apps

Answer (score 2):

As long as there's a way to connect to your MongoDB instance from Heroku, you don't have to install a Heroku add-on. Set an environment variable (using `heroku config`) that your code can use to make a connection.